# Specify timezone in Stream Analytics blob output?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

When creating a Stream Job which outputs to Blob Storage, one has to specify a "Path Pattern", such as:

```
telemetry/{date}/{time}
```

This appears to be in UTC, and even when specifying just a {date}, the timezone is relevant.

What time is it using for this and is it possible to reference a timezone?
Is it using the TIMESTAMP, and if so, can I modify that with a timezone?

EDIT: 2/27/2017 - here is a typical query I'm working with:

```
SELECT
    measurement.ArrayValue.Taken,
    event.HubId,
    measurement.ArrayValue.CollectorId,
    measurement.ArrayValue.SensorId,
    measurement.ArrayValue.SensorValue
INTO
    [BlobStorage]
FROM
    [IoTHub] as event
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.Measurements) as measurement
```

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0):

The time will always be based on UTC. Currently, it is not possible to change that. It will be timestamp of the output events.

Comment: Thank you Vignesh. I added a sample query to my original post. When you say the 'timestamp', can I influence that timestamp from the query itself, using the "TIMESTAMP BY" modifier? If so, is it possible to use in conjunction with a "CROSS APPLY", getting the timestamp from a property of the array object? In my case the measurement time is given in: "measurement.ArrayValue.Taken".